# Can I stop C++/CLI from adding IDisposable to my ref class?

Tags: c++-cli, idisposable

C++/CLI helpfully generates the `IDisposable` scaffolding for you when you implement a destructor on a ref class. Also, if you don't implement a destructor, but your class has a member variable which implements `IDisposable`, then `IDisposable` is again automatically implemented on your class. It's pretty helpful and much better than how `IDisposable` is handled in C#.

I have run into this behaviour when implementing a ref class that holds onto an `msclr::com::ptr` (a smart pointer that contains an RCW).

```
ref class Test /* : IDisposable added by the compiler */
{
  msclr::com::ptr<IWhatever> _aComObject;
}
```

In *my specific case*, the COM object referenced by my class doesn't 'lock' some unmanaged resource, it effectively just uses up a bit of unmanaged memory that the CLR can't see. Therefore I would like to avoid confusing the users of my ref class by not implementing `IDisposable` the class. Instead I want to make the CLR aware of the existence of the COM object by using the GC API to add the appropriate memory pressure.

So, the question is: is there a way to suppress implementation of `IDisposable` on a ref class that doesn't implement a destructor, but does hold an `IDisposable` member variable?

**NB:** often this would be the wrong thing to do, as it would prevent users of the class from deterministically disposing of the underlying COM object, but given the particular circumstances, exposing `IDisposable` has the potential to confuse users of my ref class, since it really is not necessary to Dispose of the ref class in question.

I suppose one option would be to implement a variant of msclr::com::ptr without a destructor.

Any other method to suppress the automatic addition of IDisposable would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

### Answer

Declare `_aComObject` as a handle to an msclr::com::ptr (`msclr::com::ptr<IWhatever>^`). The compiler does not then regard `Test` as being the 'owner' of the com ptr object, and does not Dispose it when Test is deleted.

Comment: When do you intend to call release on the com object and remove the memory pressure - these things are both normally managed in the dispose calls?

Comment: @morechili: if not disposed explicitly in a deterministic fashion, it would happen automatically in a non-deterministic fashion (I suppose when the RCW of the COM object becomes garbage and is then finalized).

Comment: Therefore I would say it is more correct to leave your object as IDisposable.  Let a client choose deterministic behaviour or not.  It is a disposable object, it is using an unmanaged resource.  I worry that man. c++ is enforcing correct rules and by hiding them you are hiding potential problems.

Comment: @morechilli - I thought I'd headed off that response with enough explanation of why I want to do what I want to do. I expected that response (IDisposable is the only possible right thing to do when working with an unmanaged resource), and tried to deal with it in the question.

Comment: @morechili - a lot of people will say that if IDisposable is implemented on a class, you 'must' call Dispose when possible. So I worry that exposing IDisposable will cause people to waste (effectively) a lot of coding effort Disposing instances of my class when they needn't.

Comment: All I can say is  be really careful with thinking that the statement they "needn't" is true -I have seen so much pain caused by not disposing even simple objects like the one you describe - I kept all this in comments as I knew it wasn't he answer you were looking for :)

Comment: Worth a read:http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/CommentView,guid,88e62cdf-5919-4ac7-bc33-20c06ae539ae.aspx

Comment: @morechili: yep that webpage is the 'bible' of IDisposable innit :). Thanks for the input.

Comment: The "memory pressure" story sounds slightly fishy; unmanaged and managed memory are quite distinct and would likely have their own distinct memory pressures. I.e. when there's low unmanaged memory, running the GC won't help a lot.

Comment: I havent used the API, so I don't know exactly what effect it would achieve. But I figured letting the GC know about some memory being used by the app might be better than not doing anything. I could live with not using it. NB: the point of the API is to tell the GC about unmanaged memory usage.

Comment: +1 to the question, simply for "It's pretty helpful and much better than how IDisposable is handled in C#."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is to hold a *handle* to the msclr::com::ptr rather than holding it 'by value' (which is still holding it as a handle 'behind the scenes', except the C++CLI compiler treats it as a value - 'deleting' it (calling Dispose) when the owner object is deleted (Disposed)).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I agree with the ratioanle for avoiding the IDispose implementation -- but why not just store an IWhatever* in your class.  The compiler shouldn't then generate the IDisposable implementation.

If you don't want the destructor behaviour then what benefit is the com::ptr wrapper buying you?  You can always declare an com::ptr on the stack and assign your member pointer to it in any given method if you really need it.

Comment: I think you're getting confused between IDisposable and garbage collection. msclr::com::ptr will release the COM ref when GC'd, whereas holding a native COM pointer wont achieve that result without a good deal more work (re-implementing RCWs, effectively).

Comment: (Or more correctly, the RCW can be collected when it's no longer reachable, releasing the COM reference)